# Reading multiple images in R for image processing

Tags: r, image-processing, computer-vision, deep-learning

I am trying to use image processing in R, which is a new concept and a new language to me. I am aiming to read a lot of images from few folders to train. As a test scenerio, I kept two images in a folder, named: n04197391_11_0, n04197391_74_0. I plan to import the images, add an extra column, and then do require processing.

The following is my code I am using:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Ethan/Desktop/R")
library(EBImage)
files <- list.files(path="C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data\\images\\0", pattern=".jpg",all.files=T, full.names=F, no.. = T)  
#This imports the files as: files  - chr[1:2] "n04197391_11_0" "n04197391_74_0"
mypic1 <- list()
for (i in 1:length(files))
{
  mypic1[[i]] <- readImage(files[i])
}
print(mypic1[[1]])
```

The following is the error that I am getting:

> Error in transpose(y) : object is NULL
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In .loadFun(files, ...) :
>     cannot open file 'n04197391_11_0.jpg': No such file or directory
>   print(mypic1[[1]])
>   Error in mypic1[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

I dont understand if the images are being read in files, why is it showing an error. Is there a workaround that I can take to read multiple images from folders in such a case? Thank you in Advance.

Comment: "cannot open file 'n04197391_11_0.jpg': No such file or directory". Seems pretty self explanatory to me. In `C:/Users/Ethan/Desktop/R`, there is no file or directory by that name. Maybe you wanted to supply the full path? (`full.names=TRUE`)

Comment: The images are in "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data\\images\\0" and not in "C:/Users/Ethan/Desktop/R". But my understanding was readImage was calling files, which in turn was specifying path "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data\\images\\0" from where the files would get read.

Comment: But you set `C:/Users/Ethan/Desktop/R` as the working directory, so if you supply a relative path, that is where R will look. The content of `files` in in your example are file names, not files. They haven't been imported or loaded yet, that's what `readImage()` is for, they've merely been "found", as it were. Either change working directory to the location of the images, or supply full paths to `readImage()`.

Comment: Thanks...it works.